# How to loop over shopify sections to create a navigation?

Tags: shopify, liquid

For the life of me I can't find an answer to this question.
I am using a forked version of the Dawn theme to create a site for a client.
It is a single page website + product details pages.
What we need to do is create a menu based off the sections on the home page.
This needs to happen dynamically so can't just make a menu and link to the sections via the navigations settings.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can navigate over sections, on the homepage by default sections are loops inside the global object `{{content_for_layout}}` . you only loop using liquid blocks that are inside a section.

Comment: @Onkar can i loop the `content_for_layout` object?
the navigation is outside of the body content area